# Why is it not displaying output according record?

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to make cashier program using C language. I use a structure for the record, but when I enter 1 for bar code input, it is not displaying item 1; instead it displays item 2. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct item
{
    char name[10];
    int price;
    int barcode;
};
struct item detail[10] = {
        "item1", 10, 1,
        "item2", 20, 2,
        "item3", 30, 3,
        "item4", 40, 4,
        "item1", 50, 5,
        "item2", 60, 6,
        "item3", 70, 7,
        "item4", 80, 8,
        "item3", 90, 9,
        "item4", 100, 10
};
int main()
{
    int ibarcode[10];
    int qty[10];
    int tot[10];
    int j, i, k, grand;
    char a;
    printf("Program Kasir\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf("ebter barcode : ");
        scanf("%d", &ibarcode[j]);
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (ibarcode[j] == detail[i].barcode)
            {
                printf("item : %s\n", detail[i].name);
                printf("price : %d\n", detail[i].price);
                printf("enter quantity : ");
                scanf("%d", &qty[j]);
                tot[j] = detail[j].price * qty[j];
            }
            if (ibarcode[j] > 10)
            {
                printf("Barcode isn't valid'\n");
                j--;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\nbuy again? [Y/N] = ");
        scanf("%s", &a);
        if (a == 'Y' || a == 'y')
        {
            continue;
        } else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    grand = 0;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n name Kasir = Addzifi Moch G\n");
    printf(" Tanggal    = 03 januari 2017\n");
    printf(" Jam        = 14:05 WIB\n\n");
    printf("+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("| Barcode | item    \t\t\t| price     \t\t| quantity  \t| Total   |\n");
    printf("+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    for (k = 0; k <= j; k++)
    {
        grand += tot[k];
        printf("|    %d \t  | %s\t                | %d\t\t       | %d\t\t\t| %d |\n", ibarcode[k], detail[k].name, detail[k].price, qty[k], tot[k]);
    }
    printf("+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  Total Yang Harus Dibayarkan  =  %d |\n", grand);
    printf("+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
}
```

Comment: Using `scanf("%s", &a);` with `char a;` is a recipe for disaster.  You're telling `scanf()` there's enough space for at least two characters (a letter and a null byte to terminate the string) in a single `char` — and there isn't.  You should probably be using `scanf(" %c", &a);` where the space before the `%` is crucial — it skips stray newlines and other white space.

Comment: Your code isn't dreadfully happy when you select barcode 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using the correct index into `detail` when you print the receipt. You're printing the fields from `detail[k]`, but `k` isn't the index of the item that the customer purchased, it's just the current iteration of the `for()` loop.

You need to save the index `i` that you found when searching `detail` in the first loop to get the price.

Instead of lots of separate arrays, it would be better to have another struct that contains the purchase details. It can use a pointer to refer to the item in the `details` array.

```
struct purchase {
    struct item *item;
    int qty;
    int tot;
} items[10];
```

Then your first loop would look like:

```
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    int barcode;
    scanf("%d", &barcode);
    int item_found = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (barcode == detail[i].barcode)
        {
            int qty;
            printf("item : %s\n", detail[i].name);
            printf("price : %d\n", detail[i].price);
            printf("enter quantity : ");
            scanf("%d", qty);
            items[j].qty = qty;
            items[j].tot = qty * deatail[i].price;
            items[j].item = &detail[i];
            item_found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!item_found) {
    {
        printf("Barcode isn't valid'\n");
        j--;
        break;
    } 
}
```

Then you can access the detail info when printing the receipt:

```
for (k = 0; k <= j; k++)
{
    grand += tot[k];
    printf("|    %d \t  | %s\t                | %d\t\t       | %d\t\t\t| %d |\n", item[k].item->barcode, item[k].item->name, item[k].item->price, item[k].qty, item[k].tot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ indexing starts from 0 not 1.

ibarcode[10] means that there are indexes from 0 to 9.

Comment: @AddzifiMochGumelar it was general comment about your code. BTW we are not 'bro'.

Comment: He's not using the input as the array index, he's comparing it to `detail[i].barcode`.

Comment: @barmar  so how to make input as the array?